# Images stacking in a a column instead of in a single row

Tags: html

I would like these images to render horizontally in 1 row as opposed to on 2 separate lines. Adding the text under the images made the images move to separate lines because of the width. How do I make the title text the same width as the image?

```
                    <img src="image.png" width="" alt="" style="width:100%;max-width:66px;height:auto; padding:15px"><span style="font-family: 'Gotham Rounded Book', Arial, sans-serif;Margin:0;font-size:24px;Margin-bottom:10px;max-width:66px;"><p>Shop Auto</p></span>

                   <img src="image.png.png" width="" alt="" style="width:100%;max-width:66px;height:auto;padding:15px"><span style="font-family: 'Gotham Rounded Book', Arial, sans-serif;Margin:0;font-size:24px;Margin-bottom:10px;max-width:66px;"><p>Shop Home</p></span>

          </div>      
          </tr></tbody>
        </table>
    </td>
```

Comment: I would say You can try to update the width from 100% to be 50% or less for each one. Also remove that padding meanwhile You are updating the width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you want to wrap the `img` and `span` inside a `div` or similar and set these to either float next to each other or use flexbox to align and size them. Then the contents of these `div`s can't exceed the wrapper, so your images can still stay on the same line.

Have a look at: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0):

there's a lot wrong with your code. But for the issue at hand your p elements are displaying as block, make the display inline and you will have the labels side by side

```css
p{
display:inline;
}
```

```html
<tr>
    <td class="full-width image" style="padding-top:0;padding-bottom:0;padding-right:;padding-left:0;">
      <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" style="border-spacing:0;font-family:;color:;">
        <tbody><tr>
        <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" valign="top" align="center">
                <div class="row" style="padding-bottom: 0px; padding-top: 0px;">

                    <img src="image.png" width="" alt="" style="width:100%;max-width:66px;height:auto; padding:15px"><span style="font-family: 'Gotham Rounded Book', Arial, sans-serif;Margin:0;font-size:24px;Margin-bottom:10px;max-width:66px;"><p>Shop Auto</p></span>

                   <img src="image.png.png" width="" alt="" style="width:100%;max-width:66px;height:auto;padding:15px"><span style="font-family: 'Gotham Rounded Book', Arial, sans-serif;Margin:0;font-size:24px;Margin-bottom:10px;max-width:66px;"><p>Shop Home</p></span>

          </div>      
          </tr></tbody>
        </table>
    </td>
```